# Как тут все работает? Особенно счетчик

Tags: java

Не очень понятно как тут все работает и особенно счетчик.
Буду благодарен если "на пальцах" объясните что тут и как пошагово происходит...

```
    public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double metrs, inches;
        int counter;

        counter = 0;
        for (metrs = 1; metrs <= 144; metrs++) {
            inches = metrs * 3.7854;
            System.out.println(metrs + " метрам соответствует " + inches + " дюймов.");

            counter++;
            if (counter == 12) {
                System.out.println();
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Счетчик увеличивается на каждом круге на 1.

Comment: Формула неправильная. В одном метре почти 40 дюймов, а не 3,7.

Comment: Лучше набери на ютубе уроки по Java и смотри с самого начала, такие примеры бестолку разбирать так как это основа основ.. После 2-4 уроков на ютубе такие вопросы как этот отпадут!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double metrs, inches; // объявляем переменные длины
    int counter; // объявляем переменную счетчика

    counter = 0; // присваиваем значение 0 для счетчика
    for (metrs = 1; metrs <= 144; metrs++) { // стартует цикл от 1 до 144 и на каждом проходе переменная metrs увеличивается на +1
        inches = metrs * 3.7854; // вычисляем дюймы используя текущее значение переменной merts (inches = 1*3.7854...144*3.7854)
        System.out.println(metrs + " метрам соответствует " + inches + " дюймов.");

        counter++; // увеличиваем счетчик на +1 (обычный инкремент)
        if (counter == 12) { // когда счетчик достигает значения 12 мы его обнуляем и печатает пустую строку
            System.out.println(); // печатаем пустую строку
            counter = 0; // присваиваем значение счетчику 0 то есть обнуляем
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Запускается приложение -> Запускается метод `main` -> В нем объявляются переменные: Две переменные типа `double`, для чисел с плавающей точкой, с названиями `metrs, inches`. И одна переменная типа `int`, для целых чисел, с названием `counter`. -> Присаваиваем переменной `counter` значение 0.

Далее запускается цикл. В его условии даем переменной `metrs` значение 1.0 и говорим ему выполнятся пока значение `metrs` меньше или равно 144. в конце каждой итерации добавляем к `metrs` + 1.0

Происходящее уже в цикле:

Переменной `inches` присваиваем значение `metrs` умноженное на 3.7854
Выводим в консоль значение `metrs` и `inches` с описанием
Прибавляем к значению `counter` +1 (инкрементируем)

Запускается оператор `if`, который проверяет условие. Если значение переменной `counter` равно 12 то с помощью `System.out.println()` создаем пустую строку в выводе, а затем присваиваем переменной `counter` значение 0.
Если `counter` не равен 12 то это действие пропускается и начинается новая итерация цикла `for`.